# Browser add additional height to html

Tags: html, lamp

I have problem on my linux ubuntu...
i have installed lamp server, and today i notice this(html is copy/paste from w3scool):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

when i open it using localhost i get this:

```
<html style="height: 688px; "><head></head><body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>



<div style="clear: both; "></div></body></html>
```

My question is, from where browser takes this additional inline style in html tag(`<html style="height: 688px; ">`)?
Because of this, my page alway have scrollbar(height > 100%).
But if i open same file like so: left click, open with google chrome there is no scrollbar...
i dont get it...

Comment: There's also the clear hack div, it seems. And the doctype missing... or is it a misscopy?

Comment: no it's clean copy.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

i try with my old project...everywhere they works gr8, but here i alway get additional width...so i realy dont get it...:>

Comment: What browsers have you tried? Does it behave in the same way in every browser? And the code... did you get it from inspect element? or from "view source"?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "open it using localhost" as opposed to "left click, open with google chrome"?

Comment: Probably means he's running it directly from the file system as opposed to running it through the Apache Server in LAMP

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `<title></title>` tag.
Not sure if you also need the `<head></head>`

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Klemzy Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>    
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```